# convertir código php en perl con modulo CGI

Tags: php, html, perl

Quiero convertir este código de PHP a Perl para usarlo con el módulo CGI.

```
<?php 
session_start();
include('dbconnect.php');
if(isset($_POST["category"])){
    $category_query="SELECT * FROM categorias";
    $run_query=mysqli_query($conn,$category_query);
    echo "<div class='nav nav-pills nav-stacked'>
                <li class='active'><a href='#'><h4>Categorias</h4></a></li>";
    if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query)){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)){
            $cid=$row['cat_id'];
            $cat_name=$row['cat_title'];
            echo "<li><a href='#' class='category' cid='$cid'>$cat_name</a></li>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }
}

if(isset($_POST["brand"])){
    $category_query="SELECT * FROM marcas";
    $run_query=mysqli_query($conn,$category_query);
    echo "<div class='nav nav-pills nav-stacked'>
                <li class='active'><a href='#'><h4>Marcas</h4></a></li>";
    if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query)){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)){
            $bid=$row['brand_id'];
            $brand_name=$row['brand_title'];
            echo "<li><a href='#' class='brand' bid='$bid'>$brand_name</a></li>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
if(isset($_POST['page']))
{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM products";
    $run_query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($run_query);
    $pageno=ceil($count/6);
    for($i=1;$i<=$pageno;$i++)
    {
        echo "
            <li><a href='#' page='$i' class='page'>$i</a></li>
        ";
    }
}
if(isset($_POST['getProduct'])){

    $limit= 6;
    if(isset($_POST['setPage'])){
        $pageno=$_POST['pageNumber'];
        $start=($pageno * $limit)-$limit;
    }
    else{$start=0;}
    if(isset($_POST['price_sorted'])){
        $product_query="SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY product_price";
    }
    elseif(isset($_POST['pop_sorted'])){
        $product_query="SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY RAND()";
    }
    else{
    $product_query="SELECT * FROM products LIMIT $start,$limit";
    }
    $run_query=mysqli_query($conn,$product_query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query)){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)){
            $pro_id=$row['product_id'];
            $pro_cat=$row['product_cat'];
            $brand=$row['product_brand'];
            $title=$row['product_title'];
            $price=$row['product_price'];
            $img=$row['product_image'];

            echo "<div class='col-md-4'>
                        <div class='panel panel-info'>
                            <div class='panel-heading'>$title</div>
                            <div class='panel-body'>
                            <a href='#' class='imageproduct' pid='$pro_id'>
                                <img src='assets/prod_images/$img' style='width:200px; height:250px;' >
                            </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class='panel-heading'>$ $price
                            <button pid='$pro_id' class='quicklook btn btn-danger btn-xs' style='float:right;'>Ver</button>&nbsp;
                            <button pid='$pro_id' class='product btn btn-danger btn-xs' style='float:right;'>añadir al carrito</button>
                            </div>
                        </div></div>";
        }
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['get_selected_Category']) || isset($_POST['get_selected_brand']) || isset($_POST['search']) || isset($_POST['price_sorted']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['get_selected_Category'])){
        $cid=$_POST['cat_id'];
        $sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_cat=$cid";
    }
    elseif(isset($_POST['get_selected_brand'])){
        $bid=$_POST['brand_id'];
        $sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_brand=$bid";
        if(isset($_POST['price_sorted'])){
        $sql="SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY product_price";
        }
    }
    elseif(isset($_POST['search'])){
        $keyword=$_POST['keyword'];
        $sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_keywords LIKE '%$keyword%'";
        if(isset($_POST['price_sorted'])){
        $sql="SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY product_price";
    }
    }
    $run_query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)){
        $pro_id=$row['product_id'];
            $pro_cat=$row['product_cat'];
            $brand=$row['product_brand'];
            $title=$row['product_title'];
            $price=$row['product_price'];
            $img=$row['product_image'];

            echo "<div class='col-md-4'>
                        <div class='panel panel-info'>
                            <div class='panel-heading'>$title</div>
                            <div class='panel-body' class='imageproduct' pid='$pro_id'><img src='assets/prod_images/$img' style='width:200px; height:250px;'></div>
                            <div class='panel-heading'>$ $price
                            <button pid='$pro_id' class='quicklook btn btn-warning btn-xs' style='float:right;'>Quick look</button>&nbsp;
                            <button pid='$pro_id' class='product btn btn-danger btn-xs' style='float:right;'>Add to Cart</button>

                            </div>
                        </div></div>";
    }


}

    if(isset($_POST['addToProduct'])){
        if(!(isset($_SESSION['uid']))){echo "
                    <div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>
                <strong>Hey there!</strong> Sign in to buy stuff!
            </div>
                ";}
        else{
        $pid=$_POST['proId'];
        $uid=$_SESSION['uid'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE p_id = '$pid' AND user_id = '$uid'";
        $run_query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $count=mysqli_num_rows($run_query);
        if($count>0)
        {
            echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>
                <strong>Success!</strong> Already added!
            </div>";
        }
        else
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = '$pid'";
            $run_query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query);
            $id = $row["product_id"];
            $pro_title = $row["product_title"];
            $pro_image = $row["product_image"];
            $pro_price = $row["product_price"];


            $sql="INSERT INTO cart(p_id,ip_add,user_id,product_title,product_image,qty,price,total_amount) VALUES('$pid','0.0.0.0','$uid','$pro_title','$pro_image','1','$pro_price','$pro_price')";
            $run_query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            if($run_query){
                echo "
                    <div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>
                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>
                <strong>Success!</strong> Product added to cart!
            </div>
                ";
            }
        }
        }
    }


if(isset($_POST['cartmenu']) || isset($_POST['cart_checkout']))
{
    $uid=$_SESSION['uid'];
    $sql="SELECT * FROM cart WHERE user_id='$uid'";
    $run_query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($run_query);
    if($count>0){
        $i=1;
        $total_amt=0;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_query))
    {
        $sl=$i++;
        $pid=$row['p_id'];
        $product_image=$row['product_image'];
        $product_title=$row['product_title'];
        $product_price=$row['price'];
        $qty=$row['qty'];
        $total=$row['total_amount'];
        $price_array=array($total);
        $total_sum=array_sum($price_array);
        $total_amt+=$total_sum;

        if(isset($_POST['cartmenu']))
        {
            echo "
            <div class='row'>
                                <div class='col-md-3'>$sl</div>
                                <div class='col-md-3'><img src='assets/prod_images/$product_image' width='60px' height='60px'></div>
                                <div class='col-md-3'>$product_title</div>
                                <div class='col-md-3'>$ $product_price</div>
            </div>
        ";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-md-2'><a href='#' remove_id='$pid' class='btn btn-danger remove'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>
                    <a href='#' update_id='$pid' class='btn btn-success update'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign'></span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-md-2'><img src='assets/prod_images/$product_image' width='60px' height='60px'></div>
                    <div class='col-md-2'>$product_title</div>
                    <div class='col-md-2'><input class='form-control price' type='text' size='10px' pid='$pid' id='price-$pid' value='$product_price' disabled></div>
                    <div class='col-md-2'><input class='form-control qty' type='text' size='10px' pid='$pid' id='qty-$pid' value='$qty'></div>
                    <div class='col-md-2'><input class='total form-control price' type='text' size='10px' pid='$pid' id='amt-$pid' value='$total' disabled></div>
                </div>
            ";
        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['cart_checkout'])){
    echo "
        <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-md-8'></div>
                    <div class='col-md-4'>
                        <b>Total: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$$total_amt</b>
                    </div>
                </div>
    ";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: ¿Con qué fin? PHP resuelve la mayoría de los problemas que puedas enfrentar. Tu única opción es aprender PERL y escribir el equivalente.

Comment: es que necesitó tener el equivalente a ese código pero no sé como ... ya que el isset no esta en perl y otras palabras que en php si están

Answer (score 1):

No sabemos lo que hace session_start(), pero podría ser algo relacionado con el control de sesiones en HTTP o cookies. Para ello, puedes usar CGI::Session.

Para conectarte a bases de datos en SQL debes usar el módulo DBI.

Para recuperar los valores enviados por POST usa el módulo CGI.

La función isset() lo que hace es comprobar si una variable contiene algún valor. En Perl se podría usar la función defined().

Comment: muchas gracias.

Comment: Efectivamente, PHP te da todo ya "masticado". [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php) básicamente popula al array `$_SESSION` con todos los valores de la sesión... Lo mismo que harías en las primeras 10 líneas con `CGI::Session`.